# Autosearching CAGE codes

Tags: excel, vba

I need to retrieve the attributes for roughly 500 CAGE codes from the DLA and record them in my spreadsheet. I'm starting by trying to retrieve it for one item, then eventually looping it. I keep on getting an error for the below and I can't figure out why.

Note the code doesn't work unless you've already opened the website before and haven't closed the broswer (you need to accept the terms and conditions).

The cell B2 = https://cage.dla.mil/Search/Results?q=07187&page=1

```
Sub NSCM()

Dim ie As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("INTERNETEXPLORER.APPLICATION")

'Retrieve CAGE Code
Dim CAGE As String
CAGE = Range("B2").Value


'Navigate to Cage Code general Page
ie.navigate CAGE

ie.Visible = True

While ie.Busy

    DoEvents

Wend


'Follow link to details page
For Each ele In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    If InStr(ele.innerText, "Details") > 0 Then ele.Click
Next

Do While ie.Busy Or _
    ie.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
    Loop

'Pull Data

Dim count As Long
Dim erow As Long

Set HTML = ie.document

Set elements = HTML.getElementsByID(“detail_topsection”)

count = 0
For Each element In elements
    If element.className = “result” Then
        enter code hereerow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        Cells(erow, 1) = HTML.getElementsByTagName(“span”)(10).innerText
        Center code hereells(erow, 1) = HTML.getElementsByTagName(“span”)(14).innerText
        count = count + 1
    End If
Next element

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error and where does it occur?

Answer (score 1):

```
Set elements = HTML.getElementsByID(“detail_topsection”)
```

should be

```
Set element = HTML.getElementByID(“detail_topsection”)  'no "s"
```

Element Id's on a page should be unique, so `getElementByID` returns a single element (or nothing), not a collection of elements like `getElementsByTagName`

Comment: Thanks for the help Tim. I was able to solve that issue, and have since been able to start to loop it, but am experiencing an issue navigating during the second loop.  I keep on getting the error "method navigate of object iwebbrowser2 failed" and I'm not sure why. I've edited to the original post to reflect the current code

Comment: It's best not to update your existing question to a brand-new problem: it makes the existing answers useless to anyone else, and this is not a rolling process: if you have a new problem, please post a new question.

Comment: Understood, apologies.